# OpenID Connect based Plugin Architecutre

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

after implementing the great IdentityServer3 on our systems, we would like to open our platform to third pary developers. Let's suppose that we let developers enter after a certification progress, i.e. the IdentityServer client reference is created by us.

Now we would like our user to "install" an app on her platform. She enters in a kind of a store and clicks on Install in an app. Here we want to start an OpenID connect flow, to give the developer an Access Token that let him operate on behalf of the user.

I've thought about this flow, to reach this objective:

1. After the "Install" click we start the flow by indicating a redirect uri that is in our application
2. If the user grants the access, he is redirected to our redirect uri. Auth server is providing us with the Code
3. We post the Code to the original Redirect Uri, provided by the developer under the client registration process (supervised by us)
4. The client, using this Code and his client_id and client_secret, will contact the Token Endpoint (and our redirect_uri) and gains the access_token (and eventually the refresh_token)

Is this a safe process? I think so, as the client has the client_id / client_secret to get the code and even a user that intercepts the code cannot get an Access token, because he doesn't know the client_secret. This flow let my app (the one that hosts the shop) to be sure that an app is installed (i.e. the user has given grants to access to her data).

Now, let's suppose that this flow is somehow correct. After installing the app, user may need to configure something.

In the context of our app, we load an iframe to open the configuration page provided by app's developer. The user is logged in for sure (as she is using our app), so when the iframe is loaded the app starts an OpenID Connect flow (to get the id_token and authenticate our user). It seems to me a simple process, but now something strange happens: the user is provided by the Auth Server with a new consent screen, even if the consent has already been given. Can someone understand why this happens?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: I've already checked that the requested scopes, either during the "installation" phase, during the "config" phase are the same. The consent is correctly registered in the "Consents" table, and I tried with same redirect_uris in both phases... Nothing seems changed :-(

Answer (score 0):

About the problem on the returning consent screen, the problem was with the "offline-access" scope. Demanding this scope requires the consent again, even if the user already has given it.
Found on: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2057